# Return filename in JavaScript, removing URL parameters

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm working on a Google Tag Manager recipe and I'd like to return the **filename** of a clicked URL.

Lets assume the URL of the file would is: `https://www.example.com/file.pdf?v=1`

As you can see, some URL parameters are added to the actual filename.

The following script

```
function() {
  var url = {{Click URL}};
  return url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
}
```

returns `file.pdf?v=1`

**How would I return `file.pdf` (without URL parameters) only?**

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `String.prototype.split`:

```js
const str = 'file.pdf?v=1'

console.log(str.split('?')[0])
```

For your function, that is

```
function() {
  var url = {{Click URL}};
  return url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1).split('?')[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a URL type variable in GTM, set it to return the page path and set the click url as input:

[image: GTM url type variable example]

This will return the click url path without protocol, domain and query string. From there, you can extract a filename just as in your code example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var pdf = new URL('https://www.example.com/file.pdf?v=1').pathname.slice(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the url at ? and take the first part.

```
var array =  url.split('?');
return array[0];
```